# .net core 2.1.2 serilog postgresql sink custom column problem

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, serilog

Using .net core 2.1.2, Serilog 2.9 and Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL 2.1.

 In `appsettings.json` I have below Serilog section. In Program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, "Serilog")
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .CreateLogger();
```

I need to add a custom column, **machine_name**. However, created table don't have this additional column. Should I add it manually in the db?

Can I enrich my log by filling this machine_name field?

Thanks & regards...

````
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "PostgreSQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=localhost;Port=55001;Database=mydb;Username=postgres;Password=postgres",
          "tableName": "public.mylogs",
          "needAutoCreateTable": true,
          "batchPostingLimit": 1,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "customColumns": [              
              {
                "ColumnName": "machine_name",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 256,
                "AllowNull": true

              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]   
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

try this in your BuildWebHost

```
 return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom
            .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
            .Build();
```

Comment: No way. Still creates the default table. **machine_name** column is not shown up!